# l2ping: Keep pinging even if the host is down

Tags: linux, bluetooth, ping

I'm using l2ping to ping constantly a bluetooth device. It works fine until the device is disconnected, when i get a message saying the host is down, and the process ends. I would like the process not to end and keep pinging the device even if it's down, so when it goes up again i get a response.

In other words, I would like to get the same result that I get using ping with the option -t in Windows. Would it be possible with l2ping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`l2ping` [always exits 1 on any error](https://github.com/pauloborges/bluez/blob/master/tools/l2ping.c#L247-L252) and it doesn't have a feature like `-t` on Windows ping.
You can however wrap the command to restart it even if it fails.

```sh
l2pingt() { until l2ping "$@"; do :; done; }
```

This wrapper will restart l2ping every time it exits with an error or until you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
You can use it in your terminal or put it in `.bash_aliases`.

Comment: Thank you so much! That is just what i needed. You saved my life.